# ReactJS - two loops?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there availaiblity to use 2 (or more) loops in one component?
When I use one map:

```
<div className="board">
    {Array(height).fill(1).map((elh, h) =>
        <Field key={h}/>
    )}
</div>
```

It shows propertly field 10 times, but when I write loop inside that loop:

```
<div className="board">
    {Array(height).fill(1).map((elh, h) =>
      {Array(width).fill(1).map((elw, w) =>
        <Field key={h}/>
      )}
    )}
</div>
```

it shows nothing (with no error):(
Please help. I'm beginner in understanding reactjs

Comment: `Array(height).fill(1)` what does this return?

Comment: @aug it create array with height size and fills with "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used extra `{}` remove that, `{}` are required when you want to do some calculation, here you just want to `return` the result of inner `map`, there `{}` are not needed. You need to write it like this:

```
<div className="board">
    {
        Array(height).fill(1).map((elh, h) => (
            Array(width).fill(1).map((elw, w) => <Field key={h}/> )
        ))
    }
</div>
```

Or Use the `return` inside `map` when using `{}`, like this:

```
<div className="board">
    {
        Array(height).fill(1).map((elh, h) => {
            return Array(width).fill(1).map((elw, w) => <Field key={h}/> )
        })
    }
</div>
```

Comment: wow;) it's working now... Very thank you:) btw. do u recommend any reactJS course?:)

Comment: check the doc, its pretty awesome as well as it will cover everything from basics: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html

Comment: When I writing previously answer It wasnt' 15 minuts, so I couldn't do it;)

Comment: check this tutorial also, it will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhkGQAoc7bc&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b

Answer (score 2):

Use a return statment

```
{Array(height).fill(1).map((elh, h) =>
      { return {Array(width).fill(1).map((elw, w) =>
                  <Field key={h}/>
                 )
              }
       }
    )}
```

or remove the inner `{}`

```
<div className="board">
    {Array(height).fill(1).map((elh, h) =>
      Array(width).fill(1).map((elw, w) =>
        <Field key={h}/>
      )
    )}
</div>
```

Comment: I had a good time with the following Youtube tutorials, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhkGQAoc7bc&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b. Helped me a lot as it is easy and from scratch

Answer (score 1):

remove the extra bracket

```
<div className="board">
    {   Array(height).fill(1).map((elh, h) =>
            Array(width).fill(1).map((elw, w) => <Field key={h}/> )
        ))
    }
</div>
```

in jsx when you write out an area that you want to be evaluated you use the curly brace {}. you dont nest curly braces because you are already in a group that is for evaluation. aka you only want one curly brace group for javascript evaluation